# How to create a string that includes quotation mark

Tags: r, string, vector

Probably a simple problem, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I need to create coordinates in degree mintutes seconds using paste/paste0 or something similar. But I can't get away from having the \ stored in my vector which causes problem later in my workflow.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
#these numbers are automatically generated
deg <- 37 
min <- 25
sec <- 15.5

#producing the vector of latitude

lat <- paste(deg,"°",min,"'",sec,'"'," ","N", sep = "")
```

My problem is that using this method or the """ instead of '"', I always end up with this:
`37°25'15.5\" N`

But I must end up with this
`37°25'15.5" N`

I can achieve it using `cat(deg,"°",min,"'",sec,'"'," ","N", sep = "")` but I can't store it in a vector.

Comment: Note that by default when R prints values it will escape special characters. Your `lat` value does contain what you want. If you use `cat(lat)` rather than `print(lat)` you will see the values without escaping. When you just type `lat`, R does the `print(lat)` for you. The slash is not really in the string at all. What problems exactly are you running into when you use that string?